# Swift Function returning a value from asynchronous firebase call

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am writing a function that takes a groupchatID (String) and returns a list of Recipients ([String]) for that group chat. I am struggling with the asynchronous part of the function however. When I run the function, it correctly prints to the console the array of usernames I was looking for. Although, when I call the function and try to print the returned value, it is always an empty array because the function returns the array before the firebase call has finished. I am trying to use a callback, but I do not quite understand the syntax of it all. Please take a look and let me know what needs to be changed.

The Function:

```
func GetRecipientsFor(GroupChatID :String , completion: @escaping ([String]) -> ()) {
var returnArray: [String] = [""]
rootRef.child("chatMembers").child(GroupChatID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    for child in snapshot.children.allObjects {
        var append = child as! FIRDataSnapshot
        returnArray.append((append.key as String))
        print("Return Array Currently Contains: \(returnArray)")
        //The above printout works properly and when the for loop finishes, the array is exactly as I want it
    }
    completion(returnArray)
    //BUT, this portion returns an empty array
})
}
```

How I call the function:

```
GetRecipientsFor(GroupChatID: gchatID) { (result) -> () in
        print(result)
    }
```

NEW Function Call

```
var recipients : [String] = [""]
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    GetRecipientsFor(GroupChatID: gchatID) { result in
    print(result) //PRINTS CORRECTLY!!!
    recipients = result
    }
}
print(recipients) //PRINTS A BLANK ARRAY
```

Comment: `GetRecipientsFor(GroupChatID: gchatID) { (result) -> () in` to `GetRecipientsFor(GroupChatID: gchatID) { result in` might work? If you print the array the line after `completion(returnArray)` does it print correctly?

Comment: Yes, add a print before/after `completion(returnArray)`. There is some other missing detail. This should work as is.

Comment: Have you tried putting `var returnArray: [String] = [""]` inside of the closure?

Comment: I changed the syntax I used to call the function as recommended by @chasenyc When I call the function as below, it prints correctly; although, how can I get that resulting value out of the bracket? I am phrasing this poorly, my code will explain it better.




***Please see updated code in question

Comment: Can you edit your initial question with your new code and the problem?

Comment: Just updated @chasenyc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with

```
var recipients : [String] = [""]
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    GetRecipientsFor(GroupChatID: gchatID) { result in
    print(result)
    recipients = result
    }
}
print(recipients) // Completes before recipients = result
```

is that the last line is happening before the async call.

To explain futher `print(recipients)` happens before `recipients = result`. All logic using recipients needs to happen within that completion block. All you need to do is

```
func getRecipients(completion: @escaping ([String]) -> ()) {
    var recipients : [String] = [""]
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        GetRecipientsFor(GroupChatID: gchatID) { result in
        print(result)
        completion(result)
        }
    }
}
```

if you want to have further logic included you can call a function within the completion i.e. `handleResults(result)`. I think it would be very beneficial to read more about [closures/completion blocks/and async calls](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html).

Comment: So then how can I delay the 'print(recipients)' line until after the 'recipients = result' line?

Comment: @KylePapili I've updated my response, let me know if it makes sense.

Comment: Ok, I understand what you are suggesting. Currently I do not have a completion funciton. How would I add that to my current function?

Comment: I've added the function signature. I would suggest reading some about completion handlers to better understand async calls. https://grokswift.com/completion-handlers-in-swift/

Comment: OK, so you are making an entirely new function getRecipients().... I will read up on completion handlers in swift. Thank you for the article, hopefully I'll be able to sort this out. Thank you for all the help! @chasenyc

Comment: I've also linked to official swift documentation in the answer. Hopefully this helps, if you have more questions about closures, you know where to ask :-)

Answer (score 0):

You also can simplify that and use the firebase observer async task adding other param to your function like this:

//controller is where you need to get the result

```
    func GetRecipientsFor(GroupChatID :String , controller: UIViewController){
     rootRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
            //here you haver your snapshot. do the stuff and 
            controller.setDataForRecipe(dataFromYourSnapshot)
        }
}
```

And in your controller:

```
public func setDataForRecipe (arrayIngredients: [String]){
     //whatever you want. example: 
     self.data = arrayIngredients
     self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```