# Firebase swift Permission Denied when using securing-data rules

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to retrieve data from a firebase database, but to secure the data I should give the API the user's id, and it should answer with the user's name.

Here is my database format:

```
users : {
"x0001": "John"
"x0002": "Samuel" 
"x0003": "Rachel"
}
```

And Here are the constraints respecting the documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data

```
  {
  "rules": {
    "users": {
        ".read": "query.equalTo != null",
        ".write": false
      }
  }
}
```

Here is the method to access to my database

```
func isUserExists(userId: String) {     
     Database.database().reference().child("users")
                .queryOrderedByKey()
                .queryEqual(toValue: userId)
            .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                print(snapshot.value as? String)

            }){ (error) in
                print("error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
           }
}
```

When I call this method for example with a userId

```
isUserExists(userId: "x0001")
```

output

```
error : Permission Denied
```

When I test with no constraints it works well, so I guess the request is well written but it does not respect this constraint

```
".read": "query.equalTo != null"
```

Thanks

Comment: Please limit yourself to one question per post, as the two you now posted have complete separate answers. For #2: you can't **return** something that is asynchronously read. The typical solutions are to either [use GCD](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44050673) or [pass in a custom closure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37106829).

Comment: thank you Fank I will edit the post to keep one question onlyt

Comment: Can you print the value of `uid` right before you run the query, and then edit your question to include (only) the updated code and its output?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I changed the real data for this post, but in this case I call for example the function isUserExists(userId: "x0001")

Comment: In that case I don't immediately see what's wrong. Can you add a `query.orderByKey` to your rules to see if that helps? So `query.orderByKey && query.equalTo != null`